# custom scaling of a wind rose plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates, windrose, rose-plot

I am trying to compare wind roses in python, but it is difficult because I cannot figure out how to make the same scale across all of the plots.  Someone else asked the same question here [Custom percentage scale used by windrose.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192743/custom-percentage-scale-used-by-windrose-py)   but it was not answered .

Example code:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wind_dir = np.array([30,45,90,43,180])
wind_sd = np.arange(1,wind_dir.shape[0]+1)
bins_range = np.arange(1,6,1) # this sets the legend scale
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
```

bin_range below sets scale of bars, but I need to change the y-axis frequency scale so it can be compared to other wind roses with different data.

```
ax.bar(wind_dir,wind_sd,normed=True,bins=bins_range)
```

this set_ylim does seem to work, but the yaxis ticks do not change

```
ax.set_ylim(0,50)
```

this set_ticks line below does not do anything and I do not know why

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,50,10))

ax.set_legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have not taken into account that  the upper limit in np.arange is not inclusive. This works ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,60,10))

Comment: @KRKirov that does not solve the problem.  For example, changing the set_ticks to set_ticks(np.arange(0,60,5)) will just increase the number of lines, but not the labels and the frequency is still at intervals of 8

Comment: True. I have played with the code and am posting a solution. Please check whether it makes sense with the actual data. If it doesn't I shall delete the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wind_dir = np.array([30,45,90,43,180])
wind_sd = np.arange(1,wind_dir.shape[0]+1)
bins_range = np.arange(1,6,1) # this sets the legend scale

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wind_dir,wind_sd,normed=True,bins=bins_range)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(10, 60, step=10))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(10, 60, step=10))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: newbie to windrose in general. When  I see a plot like the one you have the percentages shown do not add upto 100. Is that correct or should I not include the 50 % when adding up the parts ? In which the total is 90 %.

Comment: I think the percentages do add up to 100%. - light blue/yellow 40 + dark blue 20 + light green 20 + dark red 20.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the magnitude of each sector represents, where to read it (do I read the magnitude from the 'pointy' ends of a bar or inbetween?), or what `normed=True` seems to do. Can someone explain?

Comment: The magnitude is in percent, normed=True means the percentages add up to 100%, read the segments magnitude of the segments as the distance from the center.